# Vertex AI endpoint logs not appearing on Logs Explorer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have deployed the vertex AI endpoint through Python API below is the code snippet, but logs are not appearing in Logs Explorer.

```
model = aiplatform.Model.upload( local_model=local_model, display_name=model_display_name, artifact_uri=f"{bucket_uri}/{model_artifact_dir}", labels=labels, )
 
endpoint = aiplatform.Endpoint.create( display_name=endpoint_name, project=project_id, location=region, labels=labels, ) 

model.deploy(endpoint=endpoint, machine_type=machine_type, traffic_percentage=100)
```

**Vertex AI endpoint** is not showing under Resource Type dropdown as well in Log Explorer.

Please suggest if there is anything missing?

Comment: Were you able to see logs before?